# Specing remember_me feature in rails + restful_authentication

Tags: cucumber, restful-authentication

I want to run a the following example in cucumber:

```
  Scenario: Anonymous user can log in and be remembered
    Given I am logged in with reminder
    When I navigate away
    And I go to the list of cornetas
    Then I should be logged in
```

But I don't know how to write the "And I navigate away" step. I already tried to "visit stackoverflow.com" or "visit http://stackoverflow.com", but with no success. Any suggestions?

I guess I could also destroy the webrat session, but I don't know how to do it, neither if it would work.